# How to open a Cordova (Android) project in Android Studio from the command line?

Tags: cordova, android-studio, terminal

I have read about [how to open the Android Studio IDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578387/launching-android-studio-from-terminal) from command line.

However my question is a bit more involved.
I am creating a Cordova project and adding to it the Android platform. This is done in command line. This also builds the project (generating a Gradle-friendly Android Studio-compatible project)

My "problem" is that in order to now open the project in Android Studio I need to open the Android Studio IDE followed by clicking on the Import option.

My question is: how to open the generated Android Studio project, in Android Studio, from command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the app root folder you can do

```
open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/ platforms/android/
```

Comment: This could likely be extended into a custom terminal command that takes as a value the current path or something like that.

Comment: Why? `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/` is absolute and `platforms/android/` relative. It will always work on the root of any cordova project without knowing the current path

Comment: Because it's too long to type. I'm lazy like that and prefer it much shorter. :)

Comment: What I mean is, you don't need to know the path if you are already on the root, so it´s easier to create an alias for this command

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio go to Tools -> Create Command-line Launcher… and make your settings.

Then open the Shell and type:

```
studio path/to/android/project
```

In my case it is:

```
studio /Users/myUsername/Sites/mobileApps/myProject/platforms/android/
```

Comment: Thanks. This is setup I need to do then per project. Unlike Xcode where I can simply "open project.xcodeproj" from Terminal.